# Xamarin.Forms: Use image from asset catalog

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, asset-catalog

I have a [Master Detail page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/) and I want to set the icon in the navigation bar to show the menu. Therefore I put my images into an asset catalog (Asset Catalogs > Media > menu). If I want to reference that image from XAML it doesn't show up, when the image is in the asset catalog.

I tried different paths, but they all don't work. [Debugging](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Debugging_Code) also doesn't show any images. It seems that Xamarin.Forms doesn't support asset catalogs, but that is not true. On a normal content page I have this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
 <ToolbarItem Text="Configuration" Activated="OpenConfiguration" Order="Primary" Priority="0">
  <ToolbarItem.Icon>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
      <OnPlatform.iOS>gear.png</OnPlatform.iOS>
      <OnPlatform.Android>gear.xml</OnPlatform.Android>
      <OnPlatform.WinPhone>Assets/gear.png</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
    </OnPlatform>
  </ToolbarItem.Icon>
 </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

This is working without problems. On my `MasterPage` (page, which is responsible for showing the menu entries in the master detail template) I have this:

```
<ContentPage.Icon>
 <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
  <OnPlatform.iOS>menu.png</OnPlatform.iOS>
  <OnPlatform.Android>menu.xml</OnPlatform.Android>
  <OnPlatform.WinPhone>Assets/menu.png</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
 </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Icon>
```

Bascially, it is the same code, but the icon doesn't show up. I get the icon only displaying if I put the images into `Resources` folder ...

But how can I use the images from the asset catalog in my XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only response I got from Xamarin is, that `FileImageSource` can't be used with an asset catalog. That isn't completely true, but since it doesn't work every time one shouldn't use it.